# Access database SHA1 hash changes after zipping

Tags: hash, zip, sha1

I computer the SHA1 hash of a .accdb file using windows CertUtil tool.

Then I zipped the file and then unzipped it (i.e extracted it) to a new location.
Then I recomputed the SHA1 of the unzipped file.
Surprisingly, the hash values are different. (The extracted file opens properly in access so it appears that there wasn't any corruption of the file)

Why does this happen? is it normal or should I suspect a broken file?

Comment: Could changed metadata be responsible for the different hashes? The "modified date" and "created date" are different between the two file.

Comment: If the hash changed then the file changed, simple as that. As to why it changed, only you have the information to determine that. File metadata won't change on its own, but metadata like creation and access times are not included in the hash anyway.